# How to run a complex query inside a Doctrine2 entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My situation is the following: I developed an app which i'm trying to refactor. I found too much logic inside the controllers basically.

I have a few calculations i'd like to be able to perform from within the entities.

For instance, there is an Entity called Agent which is related to an entity called Account which is related to a Transaction entity.

At one point i'd like to get the sum of all the Transactions from all the Accounts associated with an Agent (whithin a certain date range).

As of now i was able to refactor the code into the Agent repository, creating a method such as:

```
AgentRepository::getTransactionSum(Agent $agent, \DateTimeImmutable $dateFrom, \DateTimeImmutable $dateTo)
```

It is working fine and it is better than the old version where the method was inside the controller, but I would like to be able to ask this question straight to the Agent, like:

```
Agent::getTransactionSum(\DateTimeImmutable $dateFrom, \DateTimeImmutable $dateTo)
```

I thought about using something like:

```
Agent::getTransactionSum(\DateTimeImmutable $dateFrom, \DateTimeImmutable $dateTo) {
   return $this->getRepository()->getTransactionSum( $this, $dateFrom, $dateTo );
}
```

But i read in other questions here that this is not particularly practical nor desirable, so... how should i structure this code?

Thanks

EDIT:

One thing that could be done is having the Agent class resolve it without any extra SQL. Something like:

```
Agent::getTransactionSum(\DateTimeImmutable $dateFrom, \DateTimeImmutable $dateTo) 
{
     return array_sum( 
         array_map( 
            array_filter( 
               $this->getTransactions(), function ( Transaction $t, $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
       return $t->getDate() >= $dateFrom && $t->getDate() <= $dateTo;
    } ), function( Transaction $t ) {      
        return $t->getAmount();
    } )
}
```

I guess this would make a more pure implementation from an OOP point of view... though it'd probably be far less efficient...

Comment: Why would you like to have the entity `Agent` having such custom method? Is not that what repositories are for? I would leave it right where it is meaning in the repository and if you like to call it directly from the entity `Agent` then just tie the repository to the entity.

Comment: As @ReynierPM said: Things like this are exactly what repositories are for.

Comment: @ReynierPM how would I "tie the repository to the entity"? I'd like to have it as a method of Agent for better OOP (It feels more natural to make send such a message to the agent...)

Answer (score 0):

By "Tie a repository to the entity" I mean the following:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="account")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\AccountRepository")
 */
class Account
{

}
```

That way you can have all your custom functions in the repository and keep the Entity as clean as possible meaning: properties, setters and getters.

Still not seeing why do you want a custom query inside an entity, that is what a repository is for. What you want to do does not mean better OOP.

More info:

- [Organizing Custom Queries into Repository Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#organizing-custom-queries-into-repository-classes)
- [How to Create custom Repository Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)

Comment: Well... doing a little more research I come across https://pressupinc.com/blog/2014/11/orm-patterns-active-record-data-mapper/ which helped me understand why this wouldn't work. Not sure though wether to use ActiveRecord or Datamapper now :p